# KQL unable to filter result "starting with"

Tags: sharepoint-online, result-source, kql

I'm trying to filter values in a result-source in SharePoint Online.
I want for example all values starting with an "A".

Initial query:

Property:A*
- Results "Adam and Mary", but also the unwanted "Mary and Adam"

I re-adjusted the values with underscores, but no solution:
Property:A*
Results still "Adam_and_Mary", but still also the unwanted "Mary_and_Adam"

I re-adjusted the values with a leading dash, but no solution:
Property:-A*
Results still "-Adam and Mary", but still also the unwanted "-Mary and Adam"

I don't understand the logic in this.
Is there any way to solve this ?
With another query or re-adjusting the values ?
Property=A* is giving no results at all.

Comment: Do you use the search API or the OOTB search box/Web parts?

Answer (score 2):

Here's why you do get these results:

1. Using a space, an underscore or a dash does not change how the text is word-broken and how the property value is stored in the index. (only storing the value as `AdamAndMary` may work as you expect)
2. Using `Property:A*` means "I want results where property contains a word starting with A". This does not force the entire value of property to start with A.
3. Note: using `Property:"A*"` would be the same. The use of double-quotes would simply allow to add spaces in the filter value, like in `Property:"Team d*"` that would return results whose Property *contains* "Team discussion" or "Team deliberation".

As for a solution (not sure one better than storing "AdamAndMary" exists, but): do you use an API or is it something related to the use/configuration of the OOTB search box/Web parts?

Comment: Thanx Evariste, I use OOTB. Maybe another sigg, like # as a leading character would work ?

Comment: We can't find anything interesting in the entire KQL documentation: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference :(

Comment: If you could insert a leading "something", something being a letter or a word (not a dash), maybe you could find a way. Let's say you add a leading "V" like this: "V: Adam and Mary", a search for `Property:"V: A*"` should work?